# C++ error with classes: expected initializer before '*':

Tags: c++

I'm implementing a list (just for fun):

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class list {

private:
    struct node {
        T data;
        struct node *next, *prev;
    } head;

    unsigned int length;

public:

    class iterator {

    private:
        node *ptr;

    public:
        iterator ();
        inline T& operator *();
        inline iterator operator ++();
        inline iterator operator ++(int);
        inline iterator operator --();
        inline iterator operator --(int);

    };

    list ();
    //~list ()

    inline unsigned int size () const;
    inline bool empty () const;
    inline iterator begin ();
    inline iterator end ();
    inline T& front ();
    inline T& back ();
    //void insert (iterator position, const T &x);
    //void push_back (const T &x);
    //void push_front (const T &x);
    //void pop_back ();
    //void pop_front ();

};

template <class T>
inline list<T>::iterator::iterator () {

    ptr = NULL;

}

template <class T>
inline T& list<T>::iterator::operator*() {

    return ptr->data;

}


template <class T>
inline iterator list<T>::iterator::operator++() {

    ptr = ptr->next;
    return *this;

}

template <class T>
inline iterator list<T>::iterator::operator++(int) {

    iterator tmp = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->next;
    return tmp;

}

template <class T>
inline iterator list<T>::iterator::operator --() {

    ptr = ptr->prev;
    return *this;

}

template <class T>
inline iterator list<T>::iterator::operator --(int) {

    iterator tmp = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->prev;
    return tmp;

}

////////////////////
////////////////////

template <class T>
inline list<T>::list () {

    head.next = &head;
    head.prev = &head;
    length = 0;


}

template <class T>
inline unsigned int list<T>::size () const {

    return length;

}

template <class T>
inline bool list<T>::empty () const {

    return length == 0;

}

template <class T>
inline iterator list<T>::begin () {

    return head->next;

}

template <class T>
inline iterator list<T>::end () {

    return &head;

}

template <class T>
inline T& list<T>::front () {

    return *begin();

}

template <class T>
inline T& list<T>::back () {

    return *(--end());

}
```

And I'm getting this errors:

```
list.h:64: error: expected initializer before ‘list’
list.h:72: error: expected initializer before ‘list’
list.h:81: error: expected initializer before ‘list’
list.h:89: error: expected initializer before ‘list’
list.h:125: error: expected initializer before ‘list’
list.h:132: error: expected initializer before ‘list’
```

No, i'm not missing a semi-colon.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your definitions are out-of-class, the nested type iterator is not in scope; You need to qualify the reference to `iterator`

```
template <class T>
inline iterator list<T>::iterator::operator++() {
```

should be

```
template <class T>
inline typename list<T>::iterator list<T>::iterator::operator++() {
```

Comment: FWIW I now verified that it compiles ok on GCC - sorry I didn't test it initially

Comment: It does not compiles with g++ (version 4.4.5), any idea?

Comment: The `typename` keyword is sometimes needed to [disambiguate identifiers dependent on template arguments](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#dependent) (also [this](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#disambiguation)). Think of it this way: you have to give the compiler enough information to complete a syntax check the first time 'round while parsing a template definition. The actual template arguments aren't known at that time and (C++ having an involved grammar) you have to give the compiler hints _what kind of symbol a token is going to represent later on_.